# Is there a easy way to make sure a group of horizontal panels are the same height?

Tags: interface, customization, panel

I'm new to blender and currently in the steps of setting up my work stations. I have a groups of animation related panels going horizontally on another monitor. How do I make sure all panels are the same height? I tried to manually setting these and they just look off. See picture below.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know there is no native way to directly do this directly from the UI. It may be possible through the python API with some scripting though, not sure, coding is not my forte.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for the quick info, my ocd is kicking in pretty hard right now, I guess I just have to deal with it then.

Comment: Haha, I know that feeling, and share the frustration. Maybe manually adjust them with the help of some [ruler like external tool](https://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?q=ruler), probably not that much work for 4 panels.